# Runtime error on asynctask when I check internet connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context, runtimeexception

I have problem with `asynctask` on `doInBackground` because I get a runtime error this code specifically on:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) content.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

((I would like to see an image in a `inamgeview` but first check if the connection is active these operations are performed in a separate class that does not extend activity)) :

this is the main activity:

```
public class TelevideoInternationalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

String loc = "Nazionale";
static String home_page = "http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.png";
WorkAsyncIta wai = new WorkAsyncIta();
static String but = "";
Context content;
/************DECLARES**************/
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout1;
 ImageView imgpag;
 ProgressBar probar;
/**********INITIALIZES**************/



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgpag = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.imgpag); 
    relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    probar = (ProgressBar) findViewById (R.id.probar);

    wai.execute("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.png" );


}

private class WorkAsyncIta extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        probar.setVisibility(0);
    }
   @Override
   protected Bitmap  doInBackground(String... url) {

         return ItaliaTelevideo.setHomePage(url[0], content);


     }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

         probar.setVisibility(1);
         imgpag.setImageBitmap(result);
         imgpag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
     }  
}

}
```

I have corrected the error, but I see this in debug view now:

```
Thread [<17> AsyncTask #1] (Stepping)   
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 672   
Thread.run() line: 1060
```

and do not display anything on `imageview` then if I touch the screen returns:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException))
ViewRoot.handleMessage (Message) line: 1704
ViewRoot (Handler). DispatchMessage (Message) line: 99
Looper.loop () line: 123
ActivityThread.main (String []) line: 4203
Method.invokeNative (Object, Object [], Class, Class [], Class, int, boolean) line:   not available [native method]
Method.invoke (Object, Object ...) line: 521
ZygoteInit MethodAndArgsCaller.run $ () line: 791
ZygoteInit.main (String []) line: 549
NativeStart.main (String []) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do any gui stuff in `doInBackground()`, and you are calling funciton which shows Toast message. Check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on AsyncTask.

Comment: hmmm try moving `WorkAsyncIta wai = new WorkAsyncIta();` into `onCreate()` method, just before executing it. In fact you can execute AsyncTask as `new WorkAsyncIta().execute("..");` instead of defining `wai` and calling `wai.execute("...")`

Comment: the error was a recycle function on one method in ItaliaTelevideo I removed it and now work great :)

Answer (score 1):

`content` is null, so you get NullPointerException.  You need to assign a context to `content`, you can probably assign the activity itself, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    content = this; // this is the important line
    // The rest goes here...
}
```